# shell script + add inside the script PATH for standard output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-scripting, ksh

Usually if we want to redirect script output to file we simply do

```
   /etc/create_connection.sh > file.debug.txt
```

Or

```
   /etc/create_connection.sh | tee –a  file.debug.txt
```

But What I want is to add  /etc/create_connection.sh > file.debug.txt  inside the script , but I not sure if it possible and how?

so when I run just

```
  /etc/create_connection.sh
```

I need that all standard output will write to file.debug.txt
so what I need to add in my script in order to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple write `exec > file.debug.txt` in the beginning.

link: http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/io-redirection.html